# node - Nothing happens when running a script

Tags: node.js

I installed Node on Linux Mint doing `sudo apt-get install node npm`, but it doesn't seem to work at all.
I created this small script to check if anything was happening:

```
console.log('this is a test');
throw new Error();
```

When I execute it from the terminal, there is absolutely no ouput: no log, no error:

```
remi@remi-pc ~ $ node tests.js 
remi@remi-pc ~ $
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: What if you run `node` or `npm` by themselves?

Comment: Are you sure Node.js is installed as "node" on your system? Sometimes it's installed as "nodejs", where "node" is some other program.

Comment: After using the solution below, I realized you were right. I needed it to be named node, otherwise uglifyjs would not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these commands to install nodejs

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -`

then

`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

now run your script

Answer (score 0):

```
Below are the steps to install Node.js from source (OSX/linux)

NOTE - this installs Node.js which gives you both node as well as npm,
       they come together per release.

to start fresh remove prior node and npm installs as well as these :

    sudo mv ~/.npmrc ~/.npmrc_ignore
    sudo mv ~/.npm   ~/.npm_ignore
    sudo mv ~/tmp    ~/tmp_ignore
    sudo mv ~/.npm-init.js ~/.npm-init.js_ignore

download source from :    http://nodejs.org/download/

    cd node-v0.12.0

You may/should issue all following cmds as yourself NOT root (sudo)

Pick one of these NODE_PARENT locations to define where node gets installed into :

    export NODE_PARENT=/some/desired/install/path_goes_here
    export NODE_PARENT=/usr/local/bin/nodejs   # use this ONLY if you MUST install as root (sudo)
    export NODE_PARENT=${HOME}/node-v0.12.0 # Recommended - its owned by you NOT root

    export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/bin:${PATH}      # jacks up PATH so executables are found later
    export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/lib/node_modules # so node itself can find its modules dir

    ./configure   --prefix=${NODE_PARENT}

    make -j8  # if you have quad core use -j8 else -j4 ... it parallelizes make
    make install

which puts it into dir defined by above --prefix

when you use syntax :  npm install -g some_cool_module
the -g for global installs it into dir $NODE_PATH and not your $PWD

IMPORTANT - put above three  export xxx=yyy
commands into your ~/.bashrc or some such to persist these environment variable changes

On subsequent updates to Nodejs, just update your ~/.bashrc with new release name in
your NODE_PARENT env var , then source this ~/.bashrc and simply issue the configure/make/install as above
```